# Получить value из radio button и сохранить в переменной

Tags: javascript

Есть  функция которая выполняет "все" что мне нужно. Имитирует работу фокуса при выборе карточки. Но я хотел бы еще получать `value` инпута который выбираю.

```js
const element = document.querySelectorAll('.element');
const radioBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.radioBtn');

const getCheckedValue = (...values) => {
const [collection, radioBtn] = values;
  collection.forEach((item, i) => item.addEventListener('click', function () {
    radioBtn[i].checked = 'checked';
    collection.forEach(item => item.classList.remove('focus'));
    item.classList.add('focus');

  }));
}

const values = getCheckedValue(element, radioBtn);

console.log(values);
```

```css
.focus {
  background: #FF0000 !important;
  opacity: .9;
  transition: all .4s ease 0s;
}

.block {
display: flex;
}

.element {
background: #000;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
margin-right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<input class="radioBtn" type="radio" value="Корпоративная" name="radioBtn">
<input class="radioBtn" type="radio" value="Частная" name="radioBtn">


<div class="block">
<div class="element"></div>
<div class="element"></div>
</div>
```

Даже если реализовать получение значения в отдельной функции ...

```js
const radioBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.radioBtn');

let result;
radioBtn.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('change', function () {
  if (el.checked === true) {
    result = el.value;
    console.log(result);
  }

}))

console.log(result);
```

```html
<input class="radioBtn" type="radio" value="Корпоративная" name="radioBtn">
<input class="radioBtn" type="radio" value="Частная" name="radioBtn">
```

Я могу вывести только  в консоль, но не сохранить в переменную.

И плюс ко всему если я нажимаю именно на элемент (и передаю `el.checked = true`), а не на сам инпут `onchange` не отрабатывает.

Comment: В первом случае ваша функция устанавливает слушатели на элементы, и конечно ничего не возвращает. Уточните более детально, что вы хотите сделать. Возможно в сам eventlistener нужно добавить то что вы хотите. Во втором случае тоже не ясно. result - разве не переменная?

Comment: Я не имел ввиду что с  первой функции я получаю значение. Первая  - для понимания того что я имею. Вторая выводит значение в консоль и действует лишь в локальной зоне видимости функции. Мне нужно вытащить значение  выбранного элемента и поместить в переменную. Что бы (например) я мог  пользовать полученными данными или скажем собрать  в объект или массив